# How to fix buffered write sigterm in gorilla websocket?

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I'm writing a websocket client in Go that sends out a control message to request a data stream and then processes the incoming data using a custom message hander. I thought this would be pretty standard, but meanwhile I am debugging this for quite some time.

The app uses multiple websockets for handling different streams, therefore I have encapsulated the web socket client into a separate struct to isolate everything.

The code listing is quite verbose, [so I made a gist](https://gist.github.com/marvin-hansen/b19acec117455c577516c4eaa2e246dc#file-websocket-go) with a [self contained test](https://gist.github.com/marvin-hansen/b19acec117455c577516c4eaa2e246dc#file-client_test-go).

The critical part though are the struct init & write function, as shown below.

```
// WebSocketClient return websocket client connection
type WebSocketClient struct {
    url       string
    sendBuf   chan []byte
    ctx       context.Context
    ctxCancel context.CancelFunc
    mu        sync.RWMutex
    wsconn    *websocket.Conn
}

// NewWebSocketClient create new websocket connection
func NewWebSocketClient(url string, messageHandler WsHandler, errorHandler WsErrHandler) (*WebSocketClient, error) {
    client := new(WebSocketClient)
    client.ctx, client.ctxCancel = context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    client.url = url
    client.sendBuf = make(chan []byte, 1)

    go client.listen(messageHandler, errorHandler)
    go client.listenWrite()
    go client.ping()
    return client, nil
}

...
// Write data to the websocket server
func (conn *WebSocketClient) Write(data []byte) error {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Millisecond*150)
    defer cancel()

    for {
        select {
        case conn.sendBuf <- data: // : runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
            return nil
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return fmt.Errorf("context canceled")
        }
    }
}

func (conn *WebSocketClient) listenWrite() {
    for data := range conn.sendBuf {
        ws := conn.Connect()
        if ws == nil {
            err := fmt.Errorf("conn.ws is nil")
            logError(err)
            log.Println("listenWrite No websocket connection")
            continue
        }

        if err := ws.WriteMessage(
            websocket.TextMessage,
            data,
        ); err != nil {
            log.Println("listenWrite", nil, "WebSocket Write Error")
        }
    }
}
```

The strange thing I am observing:

- If the mutex & send buffer are part of the struct, I get sigterms all over the place
- When the mutex & send buffer  are declared as var outside the struct, reading & writing works nicely, but closing the connection ends with a sigtmerm....

I am bit perplex and have no practical explanation, but because the client gets embedded into a microservice, a proper connection close would be welcome.

The other thing is, as seen in the test, I get frequently the following warning;

" use of closed network connection Cannot read websocket message"

Honestly, I think this code isn't right in the first place, but I haven't found a simpler and more robust solution yet.

Any pointers towards how write a robust web socket client that can run in multiple instances with each one handling read/ write connection to a different web sockets?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- [closeWS](https://gist.github.com/marvin-hansen/b19acec117455c577516c4eaa2e246dc#file-websocket-go-L136-L148) misuses the `Mutex`

it acquires the lock at the top of the function - but there's return points where the lock will not be released. Just put this at the top of the function:

```
conn.mu.Lock()
defer conn.mu.Unlock()
```

When you close the client in your test - this will presumable cancel the connnection context etc. - but in your listener loop the context cancelation is only polled outside the connection/read/processing:

```
for {
    select {
    case <-conn.ctx.Done():
        return
    case <-ticker.C:
        for {
            // get conn
            // get msg
            // process msg
        }
    }
}
```

if you want to avoid seeing a connection close error message - recheck the context cancelation like so:

```
ws := conn.Connect()
if ws == nil {
    return
}

_, bytMsg, err := ws.ReadMessage()
if err != nil {

    // poll context cancelation again - as this may be the real reason for the error
    select {
    case <-conn.ctx.Done():
        return
    default:
    }

    errorHandler(err)
    log.Println("listen", err, "Cannot read websocket message")
    conn.closeWs()
    return
}
```